# Elegant method for Boolean Indexing with variable/dynamic number of values in list

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-operations

*Sorry for the title, I couldn't come up with one that described this issue succinctly & accurately.*

Say you have dataframe such as:

```
                 Time           Temp      RH     Sensor  Unit  
0        2015-12-07 00:06:00  14.912000  42.324      A     1      
1        2015-12-07 00:12:00  14.768000  42.371      A     2      
2        2015-12-07 00:18:00  14.601000  42.415      A     1
3        2015-12-07 00:24:00  14.457000  42.462      A     4
...
```

And you want to subset these data by the `Unit` column. If you have the `Unit` you want to use to create the subset you could do:

```
 subset = df[df['Unit'] == 4]
```

...and if you wanted to subset with multiple `Unit` values you could do:

```
subset = df[(df['Unit'] == 4) | (df['Unit'] == 1)]
```

The problem I have is that I am using a for loop to do these operations and the number of `Unit`s included changes (length of value list varies from 1-3). In other words, imagine `Unit` is a list of lists that I am looping through:

```
for i in Unit:
    subset = df[(df['Unit'] == i]
    ...
```

Of course, the above will work when `i` is a singe value, but not when it is a list of multiple values. Is there a way to do this without an `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to use boolean indexing against a list of conditions? For example, see the below Dataframe:

```
df
       a
0     12
1  65346
2   1243
3     63
4    568
5    243
```

and you'd like to index on this list of conditions:

```
conditions = [12, 568]
```

You can use a Series method `isin()`

```
df[df['a'].isin(conditions)]

     a
0   12
4  568
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This was just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df
Out[2350]: 
                  Time    Temp      RH Sensor  Unit
0  2015-12-07 00:06:00  14.912  42.324      A     1
1  2015-12-07 00:12:00  14.768  42.371      A     2
2  2015-12-07 00:18:00  14.601  42.415      A     1
3  2015-12-07 00:24:00  14.457  42.462      A     4
```

**Solution**

```
#use np.in1d to match multiple Unit values.
df[np.in1d(df.Unit,[1,2])]
Out[2351]: 
                  Time    Temp      RH Sensor  Unit
0  2015-12-07 00:06:00  14.912  42.324      A     1
1  2015-12-07 00:12:00  14.768  42.371      A     2
2  2015-12-07 00:18:00  14.601  42.415      A     1
```

You can then build your unit value list and use:

```
df[np.in1d(df.Unit,your_unit_value_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this Allen! This was a nice solution, but I think Andrew L and DYZ solution was a bit more elegant.

Comment: @user2970409, i guess this solution is the fastest one

Answer (score 2):

```
subset = df[df['Unit'].isin([1,2])]
#                  Time    Temp      RH Sensor  Unit
#0 2015-12-07  00:06:00  14.912  42.324      A     1
#1 2015-12-07  00:12:00  14.768  42.371      A     2
#2 2015-12-07  00:18:00  14.601  42.415      A     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help DYZ!

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
In [15]: x
Out[15]:
                  Time    Temp      RH Sensor  Unit
0  2015-12-07 00:06:00  14.912  42.324      A     1
1  2015-12-07 00:12:00  14.768  42.371      A     2
2  2015-12-07 00:18:00  14.601  42.415      A     1
3  2015-12-07 00:24:00  14.457  42.462      A     4

In [16]: units = [1,2]

In [17]: x.query("Unit in @units")
Out[17]:
                  Time    Temp      RH Sensor  Unit
0  2015-12-07 00:06:00  14.912  42.324      A     1
1  2015-12-07 00:12:00  14.768  42.371      A     2
2  2015-12-07 00:18:00  14.601  42.415      A     1
```